# matplotlib basemap, issues graphing by coordinates in matplotlib with latitude and longitude

Tags: python, matplotlib, geocoding, matplotlib-basemap

I have the following list of coordinates, most of which are just in the U.S. I checked them using google app's fusiontables to see where they would display on there. After doing that, it's obvious that the values that matplotlib is displaying are just... garbage.

According to google fusion tables, my output should look more closely like... Really, the key takeaway is that most coordinates are in the U.S.
[image: most coordinates are in the U.S.]

```
 latitudes = [37.09024, -37.605, 43.04819620000001, 29.7604267, 47.6062095, 34.0232431, 31.968598800000002, None, None, None, 44.1455225, 42.09868669999999, 42.360082500000004, 36.737798100000006, 38.57670170000001, 34.0522342, 31.230390399999997, None, 52.922530099999996, 56.130366, 38.9071923, 34.187575200000005, 41.499320000000004, 47.9789848, 39.2903848, 19.724110600000003, 38.9071923, 39.32098010000001, 44.2311717, 41.8498339, 40.7127753, 49.4928119, 55.8417014, None, 38.9071923, None, 30.267153000000004, 46.7297771, 36.9741171, 40.0583238, 37.387474, 37.548269700000006, 40.902988, 33.7489954, -25.274398, 27.950575, 43.653226000000004, 37.485215200000006, 38.9071923]
longitudes =  [-95.712891, 145.14600000000002, -76.0488458, -95.36980279999999, -122.33207079999998, -84.36155550000001, -99.9018131, None, None, None, -88.49151540000001, -75.91797380000001, -71.0588801, -119.78712469999999, -92.17351640000001, -118.24368490000002, 121.4737021, None, -1.4746186000000001, -106.34677099999999, -77.03687070000001, -118.5900635, -81.6943605, -122.2020795, -76.6121893, -155.08681930000003, -77.03687070000001, -111.0937311, -76.48595440000001, -87.8806738, -74.0059728, -117.29483429999999, -3.2155866, None, -77.03687070000001, None, -97.7430608, -117.18173770000001, -122.0307963, -74.40566120000001, -122.05754340000001, -121.98857190000001, -74.9577372, -84.3879824, 133.775136, -82.4571776, -79.3831843, -122.2363548, -77.03687070000001]


 x,y= list(zip(*sorted(zip(latitudes, longitudes), key=lambda it: it[0])))
 plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
 map = Basemap(projection='mill', lon_0=180)
 something = map.scatter(x, y, latlon=True, marker='.', color='g', s=24, zorder=10)
 map.drawparallels(np.arange(-90,90,30),labels=[1,0,0,0])
 map.drawmeridians(np.arange(map.lonmin,map.lonmax+30,60),labels=[0,0,0,1])
 map.fillcontinents(color='coral',lake_color='aqua')
 map.drawcountries()
 plt.title('Small Amount of Data Plot')
 plt.show()
```

This code plots most values in the continent of antartica. Not going to provide the screenshot because I don't think it really conveys any useful information other than the fact that this code isn't working.
the `latitude` and `longitutde` coordinates came from the google maps api (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro). How am I supposed to modify those coordinates so that I can plot them in matplotlib? I thought that the latlon argument would help me take care of this, but...

Comment: If you swap latitudes/longitudes, what happen? Some parts of Google APIs (most notably KML coordinates) have a counterintuitive `(longitude, latitude)` ordering.

Comment: Hmm.... so in short, swapping actually worked/resolved the issue. The code I posted wasn't the exact code I was working with, and yesterday I thought I had tested swapping the latitude-longitude ordering. 

I have code that stored all of the latitudes from the api into a pandas dataframe column and the longitudes into another column. When I made the change so that I instead loaded the "longitude" column as x_cords and "latitude" column as y_cords, that plotted the points correctly.

Comment: Glad to know it worked. I posted it as an answer, in case you want to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a common problem I sometimes face when dealing with plotting coordinates: your data sources and plotting methods expect your coordinate data in a different ordering.

I guess the explanation is that, although "latitude and longitude" is the most traditional ordering to refer to coordinate pairs, when *plotting* enters the scene, Longitude is equivalent to X axis, and Latitude to Y axis, and so some APIs (a notable example are KML coordinates) use "Longitude/Latitude" ordering.

In the end, either is valid of course, it's just a matter of convention, but sometimes we have to transform from one convention to the other.